# Execute an arbitrary action at the end of chef run

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way to execute a script at end of chef run that is, along with the delayed notifications (or, if possible, even after them)? Template resource's `:notifies` with the `:delayed` flag allows for doing this but this doesn't really fit if the action you want to perform is not bound to any template updates. And of course, it's possible to hack it by creating a template and populating it with a value that always changes and adding a `:notifies` attribute, but this is really hacky and I would like to avoid this. Something like this would be great:

```ruby
execute "foobaz" do
  command "runfoobaz.sh"
  action :delayed_run
end
```

Right now there's no such option for the `action` attribute in the execute resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Tomasz comment:

> Since chef >=12.5 it has become much simpler to use handlers. Any ruby code can now be executed on specific events and be declared inline the recipe, including end of run. See https://docs.chef.io/dsl_handler.html

This is the prefered way to create a handler to run something on a specific event (one can be the end of run).

---

Old answer for the record as the two first paragraph stands.

The best workaround would be to use a `ruby_block` or a `log` resource to notify your execute at end.

All resources can notify if they are changed, not only templates. so any resource which is not idempotent per nature would do.

Another options is to use Chef::Handlers which are run at the end of the chef run, even if it fails somewhere you may wish to have a look at the windows pending rebbot handler.

See code [HERE](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/master/files/default/handlers/windows_reboot_handler.rb)

And the doc about the handlers is [HERE](http://docs.getchef.com/handlers.html)

Edit for remark: It sounds like you wish to do something strange with chef, knowing what you want to achieve or what this command is supposed to do could help understanding and proposing a correct solution between notifications and handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I agree that what I'm trying to do is not a natural fit for chef. I'm trying to check health of the services at the end of chef run (only for the development setup - not for production). An alternative option would be to do this via capistrano but that would cause some duplication of port configuration (since I already need to forward ports in the Vagrantfile anyway). So the final solution depends on how hacky it gets if implemented with chef. Current solutions sound rather hacky.

Comment: For this kind of verification hava a look at test kitchen for a full stack or at minitest chef handler [HERE](https://github.com/calavera/minitest-chef-handler) and this one too [HERE](https://github.com/btm/minitest-handler-cookbook)

Comment: A chef::Handler would be great for this.  It would run after the Chef is complete (or before chef starts, your choice), and could hook into your reporting infrastructure too.

Comment: Since chef `>=12.5` it has become much simpler to use handlers. Any ruby code can now be executed on specific events and be declared inline the recipe, including end of run. See https://docs.chef.io/dsl_handler.html

Comment: @Ghilteras that's because this handler has been included in core chef-client, I'll see if this answer can be updated, but including the whole code in answer would be very l'on to read